# Gradle dependencies get jumbled everytime a fragment/activity is created in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have my grade dependencies like so :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'

//Firebase
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.6'


testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

every time I create an activity or a fragment the dependencies get jumbled like so:

```
compile
    'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'compile
    'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'compile
    'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'compile
    'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'compile
    'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.6'testCompile
'junit:junit:4.12'
```

and I receive the following error:

```
Error:(35, 0) Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler
```

I tried file>invalidate caches/restart>invalidate and restart and it did not help. Has anyone encountered this behavior before? please help!!